# Error al comparar una fecha escogida en un input type date, y un método propio. Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy usando Formik para las validaciones del formulario, y estoy intentando hacer una comparación de una fecha escogida mediante un input type date y un método creado por mí que devuelve la fecha actual como un string, y no entiendo por qué cuando se ejecuta la validación react lanza el error Uncaught Error: Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Aquí ejecuto la validación:

```
const birthdateValidation = (birthdate)=>{
  try {
    if (!birthdate)
      throw 'Required';
    if (birthdate.toString() >= GetCurrentDateString())
      throw 'Birthdate is not valid';
    return {};
  } catch (error) {
    return {birthdate: error};
  }
}
```

Aquí creo el método GetCurrentDateString():

```
const GetCurrentDateString = ()=>{
  let day = date.getDate();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}

export {GetCurrentDateString}
```

El método birthdateValidation es llamado por:

```
const validateNewAccount = ({firstName, lastName, birthdate, id, phoneNumber, email, password, samePassword}) =>{
  let validate = {}
  validate = {...validate, ...firstNameValidation(firstName)};
  validate = {...validate, ...lastNameValidation(lastName)};
  validate = {...validate, ...birthdateValidation(birthdate)}; // <- AQUÍ ESTÁ LA LLAMADA AL MÉTODO
  validate = {...validate, ...idValidation(id)};
  validate = {...validate, ...phoneNumberValidation(phoneNumber)};
  validate = {...validate, ...emailValidation(email)};
  validate = {...validate, ...passwordValidation(password)};
  validate = {...validate, ...isSamePasswordValidation(password, samePassword)}
  return validate;
}
```

Y validateNewAccount se llama aquí:

```
const { handleChange, handleSubmit, errors, touched, handleBlur } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      birthdate: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      id: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      samePassword: ""
    },
    onSubmit: values=>{
      console.log(values);
    },
    validate: (values)=>{
      const errors = validateNewAccount(values); // <- AQUÍ SE LLAMA AL MÉTODO
      return errors;
    }
  });
```

Aquí estoy creando mi componente input type date el cual está dentro de un form:

```
<div>
          <input type="date" name="birthdate" key="birthdate" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur} placeholder="Birthdate" />
          {touched.birthdate && errors.birthdate && <span>{errors.birthdate}</span>}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El método GetCurrentDateString no tiene la variable data inicializada.

```
const GetCurrentDateString = ()=>{
  const date = new Date();
  let day = date.getDate();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day.toString();
  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month.toString();
  let year = date.getFullYear();
  return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}
```